# Check if record exist in the database android

Tags: java, android

I want to check if records exist in the SQLite database, here's what I have done so far. when I search for a already existing records im getting value from EditText in list.

```
    //code from activity class

    public View.OnClickListener searchStation = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        arrayAdapterList=new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchAndReview.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                list);
        String searchTextFinal=searchText.getText().toString();
        dbms.searchStation(searchTextFinal);
        Cursor cursor= dbms.searchStation(searchTextFinal);



       list.add(searchTextFinal);
        arrayAdapterList= new ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchAndReview.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapterList);


    }
};
```

// code from databasehelper class

```
   public Cursor searchStation(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String searchStationQuery = "SELECT stationName FROM review WHERE stationId='"+ name+"'";
    Cursor c =database.rawQuery(searchStationQuery,null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: i want to check if the record exist in the database which is typed in text field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this code in my application and it works perfact...

```
LoginActivity.java

DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
String email_id = email.getText().toString();
boolean dbHelper.isExist(email_id);

// if record is exist then it will return true otherwise this method returns false
```

**Using rawQuery**

```
 public boolean isExist(String strEmailAdd) {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + USER_TABLE + " WHERE email_id = '" + strEmailAdd + "'", null);
        boolean exist = (cur.getCount() > 0);
        cur.close();
        db.close();
        return exist;

    }
```

**Using db.query**

```
public boolean isExist(String strEmailAdd){

        String whereClause = "email_id = ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{strEmailAdd};

        db = database.getWritableDatabase();
        cur = db.query(USER_TABLE, null, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
        boolean exist = (cur.getCount() > 0);
        cur.close();
        db.close();
        return exist;
}
```

Comment: @SteveLuck Ya you can put this method in AsyncTask .

Comment: @Chirag Savsani nice answer!

Comment: Thanks @MinTheinWin-ThomasStephen

Answer (score 1):

Select a single row from your table, is you get results = it exists, else it doesn't.

```
public boolean doesStationExist(String name){
    final String query = "SELECT stationName FROM review WHERE stationId='"+name+"' LIMIT 1";
    try (SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null)) {
        return c.moveToFirst();
    }
}
```

By the way, the cursor returned from `rawQuery` is never `null`.

**Edit:**

The updated code will close the database and the cursor once the `try` block finishes. This is called try-with-resources.

Comment: Don't forget to `c.close();` ;)

Comment: @EdGeorge true, it's better that way. Updated my code.

Comment: I have tried this before, is there any problem in my activity class ? the way im trying to extract records?

Comment: I believe the try with resources approach will only work in Java 7+, might be worth mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

**DatabaseManager.java**

```
public Cursor checkFavourites()
{

    String query="select * from "+DATABASE_TABLE;
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);

    return cursor;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void favourite_Click(View view){
    Cursor cursor=dbManager.checkFavourites();
    if (cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Nothing in favourites yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to add a little description to your answer and releasing resources within it.
Also is returning cursor to activity required? IMO it should never be accessible in Activity.