# Android - How to check if item exists in database?

Tags: android, database, cursor

I want to add a new item (spot) in my database, but before doing this, I want to check if this item already exists.

Here is my code :

```
for (Spot spot : spotsList)
{
                if (dbHelper.getSpotWithDistantId(spot.getDistantId()) == null)
                {
                    dbHelper.addSpot(spot);
                }
}
```

And here is my getSpotWithDistantId method :

```
public Spot getSpotWithDistantId(int distantId)
    {
        Cursor cursor =
                db.query(TABLE_SPOTS,
                        SPOTS_COLUMNS,
                        " " + KEY_DISTANTID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(distantId)}, // Selections args
                        null, // Group by
                        null, // Having
                        null, // Order by
                        null); // Limit

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Spot spot = buildSpotWithCursor(cursor);

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.close();
        }

        db.close();

        return spot;
    }
```

The problem is when I want to check if a spot exists, the following error appears:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested,
>   with a size of 0

What's wrong with my code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check my answer. I already gave ans for this question <br> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559094/check-if-record-exist-in-the-database-android/29559909#29559909

Comment: Thanks a lot Chirag, this snippet is simple and very effective !

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar problem and I use this simple function:

```
public boolean exists_the_ColumnParameter(String query){
    //Declaration of variables
    Cursor a2 = null;

    try{
        OpenDB();
        a2 = database.rawQuery(query,null);

        if(a2 != null) {
            a2.moveToFirst();

            if (a2.getString(0).equals("")) {
                a2.close();
                database.close();
                return false;
            } else {
                a2.close();
                database.close();
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            a2.close();
            database.close();
            return false;
        }

    }
    catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ex){
        return false;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex){
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("-- BDD.exists_the_ColumnParameter --","Exception",ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

***The reason which I can't pass a single ID  because it isn't a generic function, the big difference is which with the ID you can only view one SQLite table and with the query you can view multiple ID's from diferent tables.***

Tell me if I can helps you, good programming!!

Comment: Hi Merli, thank you very much for your response : ) I tested Chirag's snippet which works well ! Have a good day

Comment: No problem, mate! But the real difference is that with my response you can apply at all query's and with the Chirag's snippet just can used for 1 query and need a multple functions for different sqlite tables, my response it's most generic! Good programming!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your cursor contains any records. You can do it like this

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    cursor.close();
    return false;
}
```